# how do you handle multiple choice inputs

Tags: python, python-idle

im making a simple naught and crosses  game with a CPU and 2 player option though the first option of 2 player works i cannot seem to get the of the CPU version to work although they work on there own so my only problem is selecting the different versions, ive pasted all the code and put "**" around the selection code, i dont know if im missing code or need to move it or what is someone could help. [screenshot is what happens when i press option 1 or 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K7nO.png)

#noughts and crosses

```
import sys
import random

def board():
    print(row[o:3])
    print(row[3:6])
    print(row[6:])
    sys.exit()

# Function to return an input
#DO NOT MOVE
def GetInput():
    print("1. 2 player")
    print("2. 1 player")
    Valid = False
    Choice = ""
    while not Valid:
        Choice = input("Enter an option number: ")
        if Choice == "1" or Choice == "2":
                Valid = True
        else:
            print("Invalid option chosen. Try again.")
    return Choice

go = 0
game = 1
count = 0

row = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]

# Main program
#NOW CALLS TO 2 PLAER OPTION IS WORKING NEED TO DO CHEAT TESTING
Choice = GetInput()
print (Choice)

while game == 1:




    if Choice == "1":
    #player 1
        while go != 1:

            move = int(input("which position do you want to put an x in?"))

            if row[move-1] == " ":
                row[move-1] = "x"
                go = 1
                count = count + 1
                
            else:
                print("that space has been taken")

            if row[0] == "x" and row[1] == "x" and row[2] == "x":
                    print("X wins!")
                    board()


            elif row[3] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[5] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[6] == "x" and row[7] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[0] == "x" and row[3] == "x" and row[6] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()                 

            elif row[1] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[7] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[2] == "x" and row[5] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[0] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board() 

            elif row[2] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[6] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board() 
            
        print(row[0:3])
        print(row[3:6])
        print(row[6:])         

        go = 0

        if count == 9:
            print("game over, Draw")
            sys.exit() 

    #player 2       
        while go != 1:

            move = int(input("which position do you want to put an o in?"))

            if row[move-1] == " ":
                row[move-1] = "o"
                go = 1
                count = count + 1
                
            else:
                print("that space has been taken")

            if row[0] == "o" and row[1] == "o" and [2] == "o":
                    print("O wins!")
                    board()

            elif row[3] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[5] == "o":
                     print("O wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[6] == "o" and row[7] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[0] == "o" and row[3] == "o" and row[6] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()                 

            elif row[1] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[7] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[2] == "o" and row[5] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[0] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board() 

            elif row[2] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[6] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board() 

        print(row[0:3])
        print(row[3:6])
        print(row[6:])         

        go = 0

        if count == 9:
            print("game over, Draw")
            sys.exit()

#CPU
#need to work out solution as to why cpu plays in 2 player game


while game == 1:

    elif Choice == "2":

#PLAYER 1
        while go != 1:

            move = int(input("which position do you want to put an x in?"))

            if row[move-1] == " ":
                row[move-1] = "x"
                go = 1
                count = count + 1
                
            else:
                print("that space has been taken")

            if row[0] == "x" and row[1] == "x" and row[2] == "x":
                    print("X wins!")
                    board()


            elif row[3] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[5] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[6] == "x" and row[7] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[0] == "x" and row[3] == "x" and row[6] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()                 

            elif row[1] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[7] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[2] == "x" and row[5] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[0] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[8] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board() 

            elif row[2] == "x" and row[4] == "x" and row[6] == "x":
                     print("X wins!")
                     board() 
            
        print(row[0:3])
        print(row[3:6])
        print(row[6:])         

        go = 0

        if count == 9:
            print("game over, Draw")
            sys.exit()



        #cpu
        while go != 1:

            move = random.randint(1,9)
            print("The CPU has chosen position: ",move)

            if row[move-1] == " ":
                row[move-1] = "o"
                go = 1
                count = count + 1
                
            else:
                print("that space has been taken")

            if row[0] == "o" and row[1] == "o" and [2] == "o":
                    print("O wins!")
                    board()

            elif row[3] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[5] == "o":
                     print("O wins!")
                     board()

            elif row[6] == "o" and row[7] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[0] == "o" and row[3] == "o" and row[6] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()                 

            elif row[1] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[7] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[2] == "o" and row[5] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board()

            elif row[0] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[8] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board() 

            elif row[2] == "o" and row[4] == "o" and row[6] == "o":
                 print("O wins!")
                 board() 

        print(row[0:3])
        print(row[3:6])
        print(row[6:])         

        go = 0

        if count == 9:
            print("game over, Draw")
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: you will need to debug, get where the error is and post a smaller code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: doesn't give me a error it just dosent work it selects it for the 2 player but if i press option 2 it just does nothing

Comment: You have the condition `**if Choice == "1":**`  in between `**`. Why is that? That's not valid code.

Comment: You never leave the first while loop to check for the second if statement. Put both if statements (if choice equals 1 or 2) in the same while loop

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  I guess they tried to highlight it. But yes, OP, I suggest you change that, it makes helping you harder

Comment: ok thanks and the ** were to help people see the spesific selection code

Comment: that was such a simple solution wish id seen it new to coding tho doing computer science thanks @Dugnom

Comment: Please do not add a tag for the editor or IDE you use (in this case IDLE) unless your problem actually involves the editor or IDE.